Can not attach to container in Portainer, is that a configuration issue?
I defined a stack in Portainer like this:
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  tmp_drive:
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: "tmpfs"

services:

  test:
    container_name: my_test
    image: ubuntu
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - tmp_drive:/tmp

The container starts, but when I click on either the "Connect" or "Attach" icon, the corresponding page appears, but stalls, e.g.

What could be the problem here?
